# LINQ, where clause if field is int?

Tags: linq

Given the following LINQ where clause :

plannedPosition.Id is of type int?

pmArray is of type int[]

```
//Works
where
pmArray.Contains(plannedPosition.Id.Value)


//Does not work - will give a design time error
where
pmArray.Contains(plannedPosition.Id)
```

How can I make the query more robust to ensure that no null run type exceptions occur?

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
where plannedPosition.Id != null && pmArray.Contains(plannedPosition.Id.Value)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks Jon! That looks like it would do the trick. I think I was over complicating the matter.